# $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ then $\prod_{i=1}^n f(i) = \mathcal{O} \left( \prod_{j=1}^n g(j) \right)$?

Tags: algorithms, contest-math

I have $f$ and $g$ two functions that are $f,g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}_+$
is the following true or false?

$f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ then $\prod_{i=1}^n f(i) = \mathcal{O} \left( \prod_{j=1}^n g(j) \right)$

Comment: Assuming you meant $\prod_{i=1}^n$: Take $f=2g$.

Comment: Do you mean: if $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ then $\prod_{i=1}^n f(i) = \mathcal{O} \left( \prod_{j=1}^n g(j) \right)$ ?

Comment: yes that what i meant .. so you mean this is false assignment ?

Comment: yes yes this is what i mean but i didn't know how to write this

Comment: I'll add an edit

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: so if i take f=2*g then at the end i will have the pi(f(n)) multiplied with 2^n ? and thats why the statement is wrong ?

Comment: i meant pi(g(n))*2^n = pi(g(n)) so it is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f=2g$. Then clearly $f(n) = O(g(n))$ for $n\to\infty$, but
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n f(i) = 2^n \prod_{i=1}^n g(i)
$$
so that 
$$
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n f(i)}{\prod_{i=1}^n g(i)} = 2^n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty\,.
$$
This shows that $\prod_{i=1}^n g(i) = o\left(\prod_{i=1}^n f(i)\right)$, and therefore
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n f(i) \notin O\left(\prod_{i=1}^n g(i)\right)\,.
$$